# How to get Results from position x till x

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I want to show data from a database onto my page, however loading in all the data has some serious memory repercussions, so I want to use paging.

How do I form a Lamda/linq query in such a way that I will take all results starting from index `from` and then taking x `amount`

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllContacts(int from, int amount)
{
    using (PortalDBEntities db = new PortalDBEntities())
    {
        // now where do I specify index: from ?
        return Ok(db.Contact.OrderBy(x => x.Lastname).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName).Take(amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* you want `.Skip(from).Take(amount)` but it's not entirely clear from the way your question is worded.

Comment: @JonSkeet ah yes that is exactly what I was looking for, just post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `Skip` method:

```cs
...Skip(from).Take(amount)
```

Note that depending on exactly how the `Ok` method works (which I can't remember offhand) you *may* need to materalize the results (e.g. by putting `.ToList()` at the end) to avoid problems from disposing of `db` before the query is consumed.

Comment: Yeah, I skipped some parts of my actual code irrelevant to this question that converts the contacts to viewmodels, so the Ok part should be alright, but still thanks for the tip.